# How to mock/stub a python method and return results based on input params?

Tags: python, mocking

I want to create a mock/stub over an external library method (urllib.open()). I made a research and found mock and stub python libraries, which seem fine and I might use them.

Still, I have a design issue: how do I create mocks/stubs which return various responsed for each input parameters?

E.g: 
If I have the following calls and I need to return different responses depending on the parameters received:

```
ulrllib.open('url1', data={...})
ulrllib.open('url2', data={...})
....
```

How do i create a stub with errors, or different data for each url and data input, assuming there are at least 10 such cases?

Comment: Did you research about **python mock libaries** in the web? My recommendation is: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock (and here is a nice tutorial, which maybe helps you into the direction you want to go: http://blueprintforge.com/blog/2012/01/08/python-injecting-mock-objects-for-powerful-testing/)

Comment: Thanks, for the links, I already found them before posting the question. The tutorial (second link) is very good indeed. My problem is finding an elegant way to set/implement multiple mock_method.side_effect variables based on the method's input parameters.

Answer (score 1):

just use python mock libraries. [pypi.python.org/pypi/mock](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock)

also, you might consider a for loop for the urls i.e. instead of:

```
ulrllib.open('url1', data={...})
ulrllib.open('url2', data={...})
ulrllib.open('url3', data={...})
ulrllib.open('url4', data={...})
ulrllib.open('url5', data={...})
ulrllib.open('url6', data={...})
ulrllib.open('url7', data={...})
ulrllib.open('url8', data={...})
ulrllib.open('url9', data={...})
ulrllib.open('url10', data={...})
```

you could use:

```
responses = ()#empty list
urls=('url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4', 'url5', 'url6', 'url7', 'url8', 'url9', 'url10')
data=('data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5', 'data6', 'data7', 'data8', 'data9', 'data10')
for i, page in enumerate(urls):
  mydata = urllib.urlencode(data[i])
  x = urllib.open(page, mydata)
  responses.append(str(x.read()))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was actually looking for a way to detach urllib.open from expected responses, since this method is called in a different class.